# No matching distribution found for coremltools==0.8 (from turicreate)

Tags: python, macos, osx-elcapitan, coreml, turi-create

I'm trying to install turicreate beta 2 (version 5.0b2) on an old mac (El Capitan) but the terminal throws this:
`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement turicreate==5.0b2 (from versions: 4.1, 4.1.1, 4.2)
No matching distribution found for turicreate==5.0b2`

When I enter this:
`sudo python3.6 -m pip install turicreate==5.0b2` 
or this: `pip3 install turicreate==5.0b2`

So I tried to install the "basic" version (`sudo python3.6 -m pip install turicreate`,`python3.6 -m pip install turicreate`, `pip3 install -U turicreate`, `pip3 install turicreate`), but this time, the error was:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement coremltools==0.8 (from turicreate) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for coremltools==0.8 (from turicreate)`

Do anyone know if it is possible to install turicreate on El Capitan an how to do it ?

Comment: What about `pip3 install -U git+https://github.com/apple/turicreate.git` which will install Turi Create directly from the master branch on GitHub.

Comment: This command oututs: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3q/xfr2ttbd0gl0wzmvc267pwv40000gp/T/pip-req-build-i3ftug_y/
` and says that it didn't find the file

Comment: Ah yes, the `setup.py` file is not in the top-level folder of the repo. It's in `src/unity/python/`. You could try running `setup.py` from that folder manually.

Comment: I might look stupid, but I do not know Github terminal installations well. So, how can I run `setup.py` manually ?

Comment: pip placed the files in the folder `/private/var/folders/3q/xfr2ttbd0gl0wzmvc267pwv40000gp/T/pip-req-build-i3ftug_y/`. Use the Terminal to go there, then go into src/unity/python and run `python setup.py`. No idea if that will work but it's what I would try next.

Comment: Now, there is another issue. The terminal app recognise Turicreate but Jupyter notebook doesn't

Comment: You can't install turicreate (version 5.0b2) on your version of macOS, turicreate 5.0b2 requires macOS 10.12+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that same coremltools==0.8 error running `pip install turicreate` on Mac 10.11 (El Capitan). I was able to <strike>solve it</strike> fool myself into thinking I'd solved it by compiling and installing coremltools from source. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55327526/1014857 for those steps.

But turicreate didn't actually work at that point. Running `import turicreate` in python gave an error (from turicreate's cypython files) about linking to a library built for 10.12.

I even tried building turicreate from source, but there was a dense thicket of dependencies. Eventually I came to my senses and just upgraded to  Mac OSX >= 10.12, which was a much easier route.