# Unable to install tfcoreml (specifically coremltools)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning-model

I've tried a virtualenv, changing my python type to 2.7x, and installing it manually.

However, I keep getting the error of

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement coremltools>=0.8 (from tfcoreml) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for coremltools>=0.8 (from tfcoreml)`

When I search using `pip search coremltools` for the versions I only get `coremltools (2.1.0)  - Community Tools for CoreML` and it still won't let me get that version.

I need help. Can somebody either tell me what I am doing wrong or walk me step-by-step of how I can install this properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just worked my way through the same error, in which coremltools==0.8 showed up as a dependency for turicreate.

The problem is that for coremltools >= 6.2, the [versions pip can see](https://pypi.org/simple/coremltools/) are pre-built and are only available for Mac OSX >= 10.12 and Linux.

(I'm running Mac OSX 10.11, and I suspect the error is Apple's way of trying to encourage an upgrade.)

I was able to build and install coremltools from source by downloading the appropriate release from https://github.com/apple/coremltools/releases and following its README.

In particular, this meant:

- Manually install dependencies:

  ```
  pip install numpy>=1.10
  pip install protobuf>=3.1
  ```
- I did not have the command `cmake`, so I downloaded it from https://cmake.org. Inside the GUI were directions for installing its symlinks into `/usr/local/bin`:

  ```
  sudo "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui" --install
  ```
- From the coremltools source directory, run:

  ```
  cmake . -DPYTHON=$(which python) -DPYTHON_CONFIG=$(which python-config)
  make
  ```

  and

  ```
  python setup.up install
  ```

Pip could then see coremltools and it carried on with installing turicreate.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem for "coremltools".  The issue was the python version.

I could successfully install in a 3.6 environment.

There are no wheels for python 3.7+

(Thank you "|fried|" for the links ...)